# How to add printk functions while the kernel boot up

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, boot

I need to find a problem of a third party hypervisor which leads the kernel boot failure in the AHCI disk driver boot process.

```
So, is there any way to add print boot up message while kernel boot up? The kernel boot process is failure, so it is impossible to see printk information after system boot. 

How to debug kernel, while the system boot up, thanks
```

Comment: *"it is impossible to see printk information after system boot."* -- You need to explain that.  Are you sure that the kernel has even started execution?  What arch is this?  Have you tried to enable `earlyprintk`?

Comment: Thank you, the kernel is started execuation, i try to use HART debug acess. However, i have not found enough operating detail information to do that stey by step.

Answer (score 1):

Following are some suggestions you can try out:

1. Enable `CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK` found in `Kenrel hacking ->  Kernel low-level debugging functions` menuconfig option
2. If you have UART debug access, select appropriate UART port for early printk
3. Boot your kernel with additional debug arguments likes `debug earlyprintk`
4. You can also try adding some prints in `do_initcall_level()` found in `init/main.c`. To print the name of the function pointer, you can use `printk` with `%pS` format specifier. More details on format specifiers for printk can be found here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your advice, it;'s very helpful for me, 
By the way, for the thrd suggestion, how to  "additional debug arguments likes debug earlyprintk"?For suggestion 2 ,how to config the appropriate UART port early printk. Can you privede more details, thanks

Comment: 1. If your platform uses a bootloader, it can have an option to pass the command line arguments to kenrel.
2. Check your current kernel command line argument to see which device the `console` output is redirected to. Use that console when enabling the `CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK`